# How to register MultipleModelAPIView?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I use [DjangoRestMultipleModels](https://github.com/Axiologue/DjangoRestMultipleModels) and try to register my `MultipleModelAPIView` this way:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'category-filter', rest.CategoryFilterViewSet, base_name='category-filter')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

And here is my ViewSet:

```
@permission_classes((permissions.AllowAny,))
class CategoryFilterViewSet(MultipleModelAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        category = self.request.query_params['category']
        queryList = [
            (models.Region.objects.filter(city__category__isnull=False), RegionsSerializer, 'regions'),
            (models.Category.objects.filter(level=1, parent__alias=category), CategoriesSerializer, 'categories'),
        ]
        return queryList
```

My server starts with an error:

```
TypeError: as_view() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

And then crashes. Here's full traceback:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <_pydev_bundle.pydev_monkey._NewThreadStartupWithTrace instance at 0x7f14980e1d40>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/pycharm-2016.1.4/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_monkey.py", line 553, in __call__
    return self.original_func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/dukeimg/PycharmProjects/dorogi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dukeimg/PycharmProjects/dorogi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/dukeimg/PycharmProjects/dorogi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 426, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/dukeimg/PycharmProjects/dorogi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/dukeimg/PycharmProjects/dorogi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/dukeimg/PycharmProjects/dorogi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/home/dukeimg/PycharmProjects/dorogi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/dukeimg/PycharmProjects/dorogi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 417, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/dukeimg/PycharmProjects/dorogi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/dukeimg/PycharmProjects/dorogi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/dukeimg/PycharmProjects/dorogi/dorogi/urls.py", line 24, in <module>
    url(r'^api/', include('activities.api')),
  File "/home/dukeimg/PycharmProjects/dorogi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 52, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/dukeimg/PycharmProjects/dorogi/activities/api.py", line 9, in <module>
    urlpatterns = router.urls
  File "/home/dukeimg/PycharmProjects/dorogi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/routers.py", line 79, in urls
    self._urls = self.get_urls()
  File "/home/dukeimg/PycharmProjects/dorogi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/routers.py", line 317, in get_urls
    default_urls = super(DefaultRouter, self).get_urls()
  File "/home/dukeimg/PycharmProjects/dorogi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/routers.py", line 256, in get_urls
    view = viewset.as_view(mapping, **route.initkwargs)
TypeError: as_view() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of

```
router.register(r'category-filter', rest.CategoryFilterViewSet, base_name='category-filter')
```

and specify

```
urlpatterns = [
      ... # your other urls
      url(r'^category-filter/', rest.CategoryFilterViewSet),
      ...
]
```

as default router does not know how to treat this as a regular viewset.

Comment: I really don't wanna do that. It will cause more problems

Comment: It will not if you properly specify your arguments with the regexp within url tuple.

Comment: https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/django-rest-multiple-models/latest/django-rest-multiple-models.pdf

Comment: Your other way is to create a custom router like specified in http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/  so it will allow extra parameters.